# CSS Tables and spacing

Tags: css, tablelayout

I'm new to CSS tables, it's my first time. So I discovered that when you set `display:table` to a div, you can forgot all `margin` and `padding` (and whatever) you're planning on it's future cause they are ignored. Nice. The only property I've found to make this job is `border-spacing` but it is a little limited comparing with `margin` and `padding`. It have only two ways of styling, horizontal and vertical. You can't set the value of the side you want like `border-spacing-left` or `border-spacing: 0 1px 2px 3px`.

In my case, I have a table with one row that lies on the top right corner of the screen. I want it attached on the very top and spaced horizontally, which caused me problems. The top is okay but the right detaches from the border when I use `border-spacing: 10px 0`.

Smart guys like me don't see this as a problem, cause we can set it `margin-right` negatively, making it be attached again on the right side of the browser. Wow, whata smart ass I am!

However, I saw an little damn scrollbar on the bottom of the screen like a roach under your cooker at the kitchen. I hate roac.. scrollbars specially horizontals, so I got my inseticide called `overflow-x` and kil.. set it to `hidden`. She run desperately and dissapeared, but I know that she's there, somewhere staring at me. And this is driving me crazy.

Seriously now. I think this isn't the right way to do that and I hope somebody can teach me how to do it.

[This is my scenario on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKnQZ/)

Thank you in advance(mainly for reading this crap).

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative to using table display types or dealing with the negative margin/overflow issue using display table types?  Or simply open to any creative offerings?

Comment: @MarcAudet I was looking for a solution in that way, but if isn't any, I will accept other methods.

Comment: johnkavanagh is right. it's better if you dont use display: table for your code. This part is making your body overflow: margin-right: -20px; border-spacing: 10px 0; Border-spacing works axactly like padding for div. When you set margin-right: -20px; you are making your table to overflow body.

Comment: @Gimmy yeah I agree. I know what make scrollbar appear, I just want to know if there's a fix or I have to change it. If the second is the bets option, I will do.

Comment: You should change it. johnkavanagh code is good, and you can change the width and height to your need. if you want your css smaller you can get rid of 'display: block;', since div's are displayed as block by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways of achieving what you're trying to achieve.  Most commonly, using `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, etc isn't very high on the list.

So, here's how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/VKnQZ/1/

Do bear in mind that I don't know the full circumstance of what you're attempting so it may well be that I'm missing a (valid) reason that you're using table display properties in the first place.

You'll notice a few things here:

- I've done away with your table display properties.  I don't think you need them, and [floats](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101) do the job just fine (just remember to clear them).
- I've removed your `display` from the cell divs. As someone in the comments above pointed out, divs inherit `display: bloc`k by default. The additional dimensions set their size as you already had it.
- I'm using the [`+` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) to put in the spacing between elements. In this instance `div + div` is essentially short-hand for 'every div which is beside another div' - so all of them aside from the first.

Hopefully that achieves what you're aiming for and does away with all the nasty hacky overflow/margins/etc.

Here's the code:

**HTML (only change is to remove the row div):**

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav {
    float: right;
}

#nav div {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}

#nav div + div{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.red { background-color:#f00 }
.green { background-color:#0f0 }
.blue { background-color:#00f }
```

Comment: In the beggining the structure was made using `float` but I change. If you saying that using that kind of css tables is the better way I may believe you.

Comment: There are very valid uses for `display: table` in CSS, but it's more common to use floats for the type of thing you're trying to achieve.  Do read the [List Apart Article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101) I linked to, it will give you a whole wealth of information I couldn't cram into the answer box here.

Answer (score 1):

and can you tell me why are you trying to imitate table behavior when you have "table" tag? it could be styled pretty well also

what you are doing is sometimes called "divitis"

```
edit:
```

you can position table absolutely http://jsfiddle.net/n83kT/

Comment: If you show me how to position absolutely a table, I may try.

Comment: Do you really uses absolute tables on your layouts ?

Comment: if you use absolute is it somehow better to use divs instead of table? it works and it's bug free - what else do you want? if you so eager to resolve problems that shouldn't exist in the first place then go for it :) I'm just showing you what you could missed out in your chase of perfect tableless layout :)

Comment: I see your point, thank you for posting this option. Is interesting, but I see a world of web develop lefting behind tables more and more.  The kind of answer of johnkavanagh I espected but I just was surprised with yours.

Comment: When people talk about "using tables for layouts", they usually refer to building out the entire page using a set of table cells, spacer images and so on.  I agree, this this use of tables is on the way out.  The big reason is that for a browser, laying out tables takes more processing time which causes pages to render slowly.  In addition, the resulting code tends to be bloated code and harder to maintain.  Enough said.  HOWEVER, a small table as part of a modern layout is quite acceptable and may be the quickest way of solving a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this the right place to discuss float and display :)
But , flex is on his way, and display is already quiet efficient.

Display + direction and you could kick floats away.
border-spacing version : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/2EZ3F/
border-left version : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/2EZ3F/1/

```
<section>
    <div id="nav">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

section is to set direction .. or not
unset & reset direction to fake float ,
 else use text-align if you dislike this method.
In CSSheet, notice inline-table instead of table so it reacts to text-align and or direction (not all pages are EN or FR :) )

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
section {
    direction:rtl; /* unset regular if you wish, else text-align will do for inline-boxes */
}
#nav {
    direction:ltr;/* reset/set  here if you want cells from left to right */
    display:inline-table;
    border-spacing: 10px 0  ;
}
#nav div {
  /*direction:ltr; reset  here if you want cells from right to left */
    display: table-cell;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
}
#nav div + div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.red {
    background-color:#f00
}
.green {
    background-color:#0f0
}
.blue {
    background-color:#00f
}
```

My 2 (late) cents for a different point of view :)

Comment: In your fiddle, the section seems to keep to margin on right side.

Comment: nop, it is the border-spacing applyed to main div.to keep 'cell' div away from each others

Comment: But... that was the main problem I decribed on the question.

Comment: You may use border-left instead of border-spacing. http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/2EZ3F/1/

Comment: Nice, but in my real case, this panel is over a header with a background imagem, so white borders(or any color) will screw up the layout.

Comment: so in this case , give a transparent color to borders, and send backgrounds to 'div cell' child's. You can even set borders-width with em values if you need.

Comment: down votes ?? some people still get chills with the word "table" ?. @dontVoteMeDown transparent borders don't do ?

Comment: Transparent borders may do, but I will take john's answer. The guy who done this app used float and I change it. But if is better using floats, I will use. So I reverted what I done with tables. Thank you anyway, your answer is great.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I would like to offer the case for the often overlooked `inline-block` display type.

Similar to the use of floats, the HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

#nav div {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#nav div + div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

This `inline-block` approach behaves similarly to the floated-child-div's approach.

In this application, I can't think of a reason to use one over the other.

One minor consideration is that `inline-block` is not supported in some older browsers.

Otherwise, both approaches use the same mark-up and the CSS rules are similarly simple.

The choice may depend a lot on the content that you use in the `#nav div` elements.

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EVJPN/